# What to do when I can't turn my wet laptop on?

Tags: laptop

I had my laptop in a backpack but it was raining a lot, so it got wet a little bit.
I took the battery out afterwards, let it dry for 5 days but now I can't turn it on.
What can be the cause? I didn't put the battery inside the laptop, I only use the AC adapter but it still can't be turned on.

I disassambled my laptop and found this very famous green layer inside on one area of the motherboard. Most probably it's patina. It seems like the rainwater got inside the laptop and caused the oxidation and that's why the green layer formed there... Will my laptop start working when I clean the area from this green layer?

Look at images how the motherboard looks like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you hear any sounds when you try to turn on your laptop?

Comment: No, I don't hear any sound at all...

Comment: It's very likely that it's not dry yet, especially if you did not disassemble it at all,

Comment: I agree with Daniel -- try wrapping the complete machine in paper toweling or dry cloth towels (taped to prevent dust infiltration, as far as possible) and burying it in a sealed container of rice for a week.  The rice is a low-cost, easily available dessicant, almost as good as silica gel and lots cheaper -- and you can eat it afterward.

Comment: Rinse with distilled water and then use the cloth or brush to clean the circuit.Usually the working would depend how much the water went inside so you can try once it is cleaned

Answer (score 5):

**Take the harddisk out!**

Make sure your data is safe first. Before experimenting more, be sure to have a backup. If you do have that already - great - but still it's best to have the original disk in case your backup was not complete, misconfigured or lost somehow. (Yesterday I discovered that two of my backup methods failed over the past month, because of two separate independent reasons.)

Put the harddisk in an external case and connect it to another computer, see if that works. If that's the case, keep it like that. Use another harddisk and use that for testing.

Comment: Why should I take the harddisk out? What do you mean by experimenting?

Comment: Turning the power on is one example of an experiment! By taking out the harddisk, you make sure it doesn't get more damaged in case of short circuit. That could damage the harddisk, making it impossible to use without expensive repairs.

Answer (score 3):

It's very likely that the (rather impure) water that got inside the machine left conductive deposits on the circuit boards that are causing something in the startup process to fail (from your description, it's unlikely it got wet enough for water to enter the hard disk capsule).  The only practical way to resolve this is complete disassembly, followed by washing down all circuit boards with distilled water and thorough drying before reassembly (and even that might not fix things, because the stray conduction paths could have damaged sensitive components on the boards).

Don't try to disassemble the machine yourself unless you've worked on laptops before; and take into account the cost of repair before you agree to have someone else do the work; honestly, it's likely to be most economical to buy a similar used machine and try to recover your data from the hard disk (if it spins up, the contents are likely to be fine).

Edit: Based on the photos you added, it's most likely you need a new motherboard.  Corrosion can reach inside component packages and lead to failures, even if stray electrical currents (possibly as high as battery voltage and a large fraction of an amp) don't burn out parts intended to use milliamps and one point something volts.